# Linear Algebra Help finding a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

$$
(4I_4-5A)^-1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p & q \\
0 & -2 & r \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $p,q,r$ are arbitrary real numbers. Find $A$.

Obviously, $4I_4$ is the identity matrix as a $4 \times 4$, and I have been able to find what the matrix $(4I_4-5A)$ should be based off of $(A^-1)^-1=A.$

The matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p/2 & -pr/6 -q/3 \\
0 & -.5 & r/6 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The issue is I'm not quite sure where to go from here or if my action was a misstep despite seeming right to me. Any help in finding $A$ would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Why $I_4$ when the matrix is $3×3$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster I don't know why it's I4, that's part of what's getting me, but that's what I've been given.

Comment: It's GOTTA be a typo. Probably meant to type $4I_3$, but ended up doubling the $4$. Otherwise it makes no sense, and no amount of tea-leaf-reading will help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's $I_3$ rather than $I_4$, you have
$$
4I - 5A = M
$$
for some matrix $M$ that you've written down, and involves $p, q,$ and $r$.  Subtract $4I$ from each side to get
$$
-5A = M - 4I
$$
Then divide by $-5$ to get a formula for $A$ in terms of $p, q, r$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, I really was tripped up on the I4 since I knew it couldn't work, but hadn't figured out where to go from what I'd done already.

Answer (score 1):

This looks straight forward if you substitute $I_3$ for $I_4$.

Let $P:=\begin{pmatrix}1&p&r\\0&-2&q\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $4I_3-5A=P^{-1}\implies 4I_3-P^{-1}=5A\implies A=1/5(4I_3-P^{-1})$.

So it remains to compute $P^{-1}$, and then simplify.

The inverse is the transpose of the matrix of cofactors: $P^{-1}=-1/6\begin{pmatrix}-6&-3p&pr+2q\\0&3&-2r\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$.  You already computed it.

So finally, we get $A=1/5\begin{pmatrix}3&-p/2&pr/6+q/3\\0&41/2&-r/3\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$.